# Making images fit their parent container

Tags: html, css, image

I'm currently playing a little with angular bootstrap carousel, and want to display some pictures, and be able to click on them.

My first problem is that not all of my images is exact the same size, and they're not fitting in my bootstrap column. Often the picture is not wide enough, so it leaves alot of free space in the left and right side. Is it possible to crop/zoom in on the image automatically, so it fill out all the space all the time?

Another question I have is.. How do I link each picture to something?

Comment: Scaling an image to a size larger than it's original dimensions is not a good idea. The resulting image can become stretched or pixelated which is never attractive. My advise would be to ensure the original images are of the desired dimensions

Answer (score 1):

To force your images to upsize to their container, you'll have to apply some CSS. Bootstrap's `img-responsive` class sets `max-width` to 100%, but that doesn't force upscaling.

```
<style>
.oversize {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
```

To link an image, wrap it in an anchor:

```
<a href="/some-page"><img src="/some-image.jpg" class="oversize" /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks @isherwood - I've tried your code examples, and the link part works perfect, but I'm still having some problems with the image height. The width fits perfect in all screen sizes , but if the image is too tall, it just breaking trough the div I want it to be inside.

Comment: You an do width, or you can do height. You can't do both. Set overflow to hidden on the div to crop the image. If you want more help, show some code and/or a demo.